# IntelliSense in Pycharm suddenly shows too many entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I migrated my python projects to a new computer, and my fresh install of PyCharm has somehow broken IntelliSense. Before, I would only get one or two entries, but for some reason, now it shows all the entries that fit the particular pattern of parameters.

Both PyCharm and Python 11 are fresh installs. I also changed the project interpreter from individual vEnvs to the Python 11 install in Windows.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to get the old IntelliSense?

[image: Weirdly broken IntelliSense in PyCharm.]